# Apex List.add() always is null during test but works fine otherwise

Tags: apex, list, sobject

Below code does not when I test via test class. I debug it I see the productPackges are all there but the IDs are not getting added to the Id list.

Code works fine if I deploy and test but just test class is not passing because ppIds is always null.

```
public static void testListId(List<Product_Package__c> productPackges){
        List<Id> ppIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Product_Package__c pp:productPackges){
            ppIds.add(pp.Id); // <--DOES NOT ADD TO LIST
        }
}
```

Comment: The test classes do not have access to the data in you environment. You should create data in your test method. Reference to trailhead; https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_data

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! My first thought, too, is what rael_kid said ^^^^.  If you already are creating test data and it is not working, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/368117/edit) your question to add your full test class code.

Comment: I did create data in the test environment and passed it to the method above. When debugging I see the list of productPackages there but when it loops through them it does not store the Ids in the ppIds list. During loop as well I can see in debug it is looping through each productPackage.